# SQL Duplicating permissions

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have been experiencing issues when granting permissions to stored procedures and views in our database, whether I do it via the `GRANT` command or I use the UI in SSMS, it duplicates the permissions and somehow it does not pick up the permissions that I gave.

See here:

[image]

The above permissions where granted as follows : `GRANT SELECT, VIEW DEFINITION ON [dbo].[VW_REP_BROKER_COMMISSIONS] TO [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE];`

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [DATABASE_NAME].[VIEW_NAME] TO [APPLICATION_ROLE]
```

Please change your query as below.

[DATABASE_NAME] : Your database name

[VIEW_NAME] : Your view name

[APPLICATION_ROLE] : Specify role.

Comment: Hi @Manoj, this is more or less the same as the code that I supplied in my question. Except that you try to `GRANT EXECUTE` where execute cannot be done on a view, I get the following error: `Granted or revoked privilege EXECUTE is not compatible with object.`.